# Can you buy chametz during Pesach that will be delivered after Pesach?

Tags: passover, technology, transactions, chametz-leaven

As an example, during Hol Hamo'ed Pesach, could you buy chametz online knowing that it will arrive after Pesach?

My assumption is that it would be OK, as the buyer doesn't actually own the product until it arrives at his home. Proof of that fact is that say, if you order from Amazon, they are responsible to replace the item if it has not arrived / got lost in transit.

Or, do we say that once someone has paid for the item, he owns it even if he has not physically acquired it?

Comment: Highly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103194/when-do-you-own-the-food-in-your-farm-share-box

Comment: Do you mean acc. to Dina Demalchutah or by the Torah?

Comment: I'm not completely sure your example sets the proof that you don't own it. Once the payment is cleared, you *might* be the owner, however, the condition of the purchase is that you can return it, or they can replace it. I answered it elsewhere about the return policy - are you already an owner or not. I think that the fact that you're not automatically refunded in many cases show that the ownership exists.

Comment: Happy Omer, @Al. Re your first comment, I am mainly looking at it halachically - rabbinical or Torah-based. *Dina Demalchuta* **might** play a factor in the halachic ruling, here.

Comment: Why would you ask rabbinically if the only thing that buys is when it comes into your hands.

Comment: I also wrote elsewhere, that in Israel (AFAIK) the CC companies claim [co]-ownership until finally cleared from the bank account.

Comment: @AlBerko Please include a link to one of your "elsewhere" answers - the one that you think is most relevant to this question - when you can.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/102086/15579

Comment: I was thinking, your question is תרתי דסתרי - you say "buy" and then "not own", maybe change it to "pay for Chometz" to be more technically correct.

Comment: "Proof of that fact is that say, if you order from Amazon, they are responsible to replace the item": They are? I'm unaware of such a law. Does that apply to all sellers? In all jurisdictions? I recommend that if you're asking only about such a case then you say so in the question.

Comment: I placed an order with a site for delivery over a week later -- they said that they are putting a "hold" on my credit card for an approximate amount. This isn't a transfer of funds nor a guarantee that they will be able to fill my order when the time comes around so I would think that no ownership has been established.

Comment: CRC dayan answered this question: https://www.crcweb.org/Passover/5781/Buying-Chametz-Online-for-After-Pesach.pdf